# How to calculate the tangent vector of $h(t)=\exp_{c(t)} V(t)$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

$(M,g)$ is 2-dimensional Riemannian manifold. $C(t):(0,a)\rightarrow M$ is a curve. $V(t)$ is a vector field along $C(t)$. Assume
$$
h(t)=\exp_{c(t)} V(t)    \tag{1}
$$
Then, I want to know how to calculate the tangent vector of $h(t)$.

What I try: In fact, it is to calculate $\partial_t h(t)$.
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_t h(t) 
=
\partial_t[\exp_{c(t)} V(t)]  
=
\partial_t[\gamma(1,C(t),V(t))]
\end{align}
\tag{2}
$$
where $\gamma(s,C(t),V(t))$ is geodesic, which start at $C(t)$ in the direct $V(t)$, $s$ is the parameter. For fixed $t\in(0,a)$, let
$$
J(s)=\gamma(s,C(t),V(t))   \tag{3}
$$
denote the parallel transport along $J(s)$ as $J^*_s: T_{J(0)}M\rightarrow T_{J(s)}M$ . Then, I guess
$$
\partial_t h(t)=J_1^* \left[\frac{d}{dt}C(t)+\frac{D}{dt}V(t)\right]
\tag{4}
$$
where $\frac{D}{dt}$ is covariant derivative along $C(t)$.  But I don't know how to show it. If it is in some book, just tell me the book is enough, thanks.